# unable to determine parse mode can't fix

Tags: html, doctype

I can't fix that error :

```
Unable to Determine Parse Mode!

The validator can process documents either as XML (for document types such as XHTML, SVG, etc.) or SGML (for HTML 4.01 and prior versions). For this document, the information available was not sufficient to determine the parsing mode unambiguously, because:

    the MIME Media Type (text/html) can be used for XML or SGML document types
    No known Document Type could be detected
    No XML declaration (e.g <?xml version="1.0"?>) could be found at the beginning of the document.
    No XML namespace (e.g <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">) could be found at the root of the document.

As a default, the validator is falling back to SGML mode.
```

Now i use this :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I read some answers say change to this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Or this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Also i saved the file as UTF-8 , but it's not detecting the doctype

I don't understand why .

Here link to my site , i use Laravel 4.

```
http://test.ibids.co.il/?lang=en
```

I use http://validator.w3.org to check.

Thanks.

Comment: duh, use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. Why all that garbage if you can have it easy and clean?

Comment: No idea, i try make it the best to work .. at first it was clean <!DOCTYPE HTML> , but it didn't worked so i switched to the others.

Comment: this crap you have now is old and deprecated, use the html5 doctype. The problem is indeed with that the doctype is not the first thing of the page.

Comment: @MightyPork i have removed all this crap, now validator much better , thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your doctype at the very top of the page.  Looking at your page source, you have links to style sheets and style tags being written before it.  These should appear in the `head` section of the document

Comment: I know it's should be on top of the page, it's there , but not detected by firebug. And about those style links, i don't know where they come from, i didn't put there them, i try to check . maybe this cause the problem.

Comment: This definitely causes the problem, and no it's not there, the links are there first

Comment: @Ravg I'd advise you to disable the minification, so you can clearly see what's going on. Then, trace where the links are coming from, I suspect you simply messed up the views...

Comment: Yes , thanks pete you totally right , this fixed the problem. @MightyPork thanks i will take you'r advise.